# Import simulator and device framework in Xcode but keep the same symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios-frameworks

I am using Xcode 7.2 and I m trying to integrate the Dropbox iOS SDK (.framework) so that it runs both on device and on simulator. 
If I try to give both versions the same name (so that I do not need to meddle with the import statements) I get a "same-name" error. 
What do I have to do so that:

1) I do not need to change import statements depending on the way I run the app (duh!)
2) I still use them as frameworks (no conversion to .a files)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand your question.  What do you mean by "integrate the iOS SDK (.framework)"?  The iOS Device SDK (iPhoneOS.sdk) and iOS Simualtor SDK (iPhoneSimulator.sdk) are shipped in their respective platforms inside of Xcode and contain headers and stub libraries for 3rd party developers to build their projects.  Please provide examples.

Comment: very sorry, forgot to write Dropbox, edited now :-)

Comment: Does the Dropbox SDK include simulator and device slices in their library?  If not, that's a non-starter.